# Django form submission success message after form submission

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I developed a form which on submission is stored into database. I am using python django framework.

Now I would like to show a "Successfully Updated" message in the fronend form for the user. Can someone suggest me the best way to do this.

I would like to show the message only after the form is successfully stored in the db.

Comment: you can use django messages framework to achieve your functionality. Find it in docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Yep I used it, but as you can see in my reply for the answer below the message won't perish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this code after `form.save()`

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
```

and in template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: what this does is, it shows the message. but the message won't perish. Is there a way so that the message can perish? Because if the user wants to submit the form again, he can see the message already and it makes no sense.

Comment: you need to refresh the page, because it will render once after redirecting

Comment: yes, but I don't want the user to refresh the page to submit one more form.

Comment: you cannot do that without refreshing, else you need jquery to hide the message after few seconds

Comment: What you can do is display the message, but make it dismissible (e.g. a Bootstrap dismissible alert). This way the user can remove the message himself. And as Exprator said above you can still remove the message after a certain time using JS.

Comment: Bootstrap alert is perfect. Thank you @dentemm